# Powershell Robocopy from server to mulitple hosts

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a file on a server that I want to copy to a list of hosts on the domain. I use the following script to populate a .txt file that lists connected hosts:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "xNext="
set "xComputer="
for /f %%A in ('net view /all') do (
set "xComputer=%%~A"
if "!xComputer:~0,2!"=="\\" for /f "tokens=2,* delims=. " %%X in ('nslookup %%A') do (
    if "!xNext!"=="1" (
        echo.!xComputer! = %%X.%%Y
        set "xNext=0"
    )
    if "!xComputer:~2!"=="%%~X" set "xNext=1"
)
)
endlocal
pause
```

I then strip the IP's after using them for other purposes to leave a .txt file that lists the hosts, line by line, like this:

```
\\Host1
\\Host2
\\Host3
...
```

I have tried the following:

```
Get-Content 'path\computers.txt' | Foreach-Object start /B {robocopy 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\copyfile' '\\$_\users\user\desktop' }
```

With the following error:

```
ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Destination Directory \\$_\Users\user\Desktop\
The network path was not found.
```

What have I messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start /b` is not a poper parameter for `Foreach-object`. Also variables are not expanded in single quotes.

```
Get-Content 'path\computers.txt' | Foreach-Object { robocopy C:\Users\User\Desktop\copyfile \\$_\users\user\desktop }
```

Comment: works great! ..... 27/30 hosts.
 I had three hosts that return the error 2018/08/16 13:59:57 ERROR 67 (0x00000043) Getting File System Type of Destination \\Host4\users\user\desktop\ The network name cannot be found.
I navigated and found the directory to be \\host4\c$\users\user\desktop

 I have confirmed that they are connected to the server. How would I get it to accept the hidden drive on the host?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why, but it’s complaining about the trailing backslash on the destination path.